# How to get user comment from a Component using the core service

Tags: 2013, core-service

I am trying to get user comment from Components in folder using the core service. This should be available something like:

```
componentData.VersionInfo.UserComment().ToString();
```

where `componentData` is:

```
XElement componentListElement = client.GetListXml("folderTCM", filter);
foreach (XElement organisationItem in componentListElement.Elements())
{
    var data = client.Read(organisationItem.FirstAttribute.Value, new ReadOptions());
    var componentData = new ComponentData();
    componentData = (ComponentData)data;
}
```

The `UserComment()` function does not exist. Has anyone tried to get the user comments from a component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do somthing like below:

```
XElement componentListElement = client.GetListXml("folderTCM", filter);
foreach (XElement organisationItem in componentListElement.Elements())
            {
               var data = client.Read(organisationItem.FirstAttribute.Value,
                                                                           new ReadOptions());
               var componentData = new ComponentData();
                componentData = (ComponentData)data;
FullVersionInfo fullVersionInfo = (FullVersionInfo)componentData.VersionInfo;
string Comments = fullVersionInfo.UserComment;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you can use `FullVersionInfo` by getting the component's `VersionedItemData`.

Something like this:

```
VersionedItemData versionedItemData = (VersionedItemData) client.Read(organisationItem.FirstAttribute.Value, new ReadOptions());
FullVersionInfo fullVersionInfo = (FullVersionInfo)versionedItemData.VersionInfo;
string userComment = fullVersionInfo.UserComment;
```